# Correct way to use gnuplot in Ruby

Tags: ruby, gnuplot

So I'm trying to use Gnuplot in Ruby (not rails). I've managed to plot my data (radius of a pipe at different distances) by doing this :

```
Gnuplot.open do |gp|
   Gnuplot::Plot.new(gp) do |plot|
       plot.xrange "[0:20]"
       plot.yrange "[0:7]"
       plot.title  "Radius of reed pipe per abscissa"
       plot.xlabel "x"
       plot.ylabel "radius"

       x = abs
       y = rad
       plot.data << Gnuplot::DataSet.new([x, y]) do |ds|
        ds.with "lines"
        ds.notitle
       end
    end
end
```

So far, so good. The issue is that now, I am trying to draw the shape of this object, so I'd like to draw a circle in 3d around the x-axis of radius rad[i] at position abs[i], for every i in the abs.

This is where I started to feel lost because all the tutorials and examples I could find were using Gnuplot as a script, and I just don't understand how you're supposed to make it work in Ruby (example: http://www.gnuplotting.org/code/sand_density2.gnu).

For instance, to draw a circle, I'm seeing this a lot (from the example above):

```
   set object 1 circle front at 0,0 size r fillcolor rgb "black" lw 4
```

but I have no clue how to make that work in Ruby, the documentation is extremely poor (https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/gnuplot/2.6.2/Gnuplot/Plot), the few examples given in Ruby in the github (https://github.com/rdp/ruby_gnuplot) do not explain how to do more advanced stuff, and I overall find very few information about this topic.

The real question here is how do you properly use all of Gnuplot features, such as this one, in Ruby?

Comment: "...how do you properly use all of Gnuplot features.."? That's quite a broad request and, as such, makes your question off-topic. Restrict your question to one, or, at most, two closely related questions. Asking for how to use them all constitutes writing an entire tutorial.

Comment: Hacky, but easy, solution: use Ruby to generate a regular gnuplot script

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not asking for an explanation for every single command separately, but rather, the way you're supposed to: are you supposed to somehow use the Gnuplot script language, or find each command's equivalent in Ruby. That is the whole point of this question, as the title points out. I just added explanations on why I needed that, and what I'm doing

Comment: @Max Uh, I don't understand what you mean by that, could you explain?

Comment: gnuplot has its own syntax that it can read from a text file to generate a plot (which is what most of the docs cover). You can use Ruby to generate such a text file programmatically

Comment: Mh I think I got it. In my case, I could write a gnuplot script to plot that pipe from the abscissa and radius produced by my ruby program that I could write in a file. I'll try it out and upload an answer if it does the trick !

Answer (score 3):

Try numo-gnuplot

https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-gnuplot

You see a lot of examples here.

https://github.com/ruby-numo/numo-gnuplot-demo

For example:

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'numo/gnuplot'


x = [1,2,3,4,5]
y = [2,3,2,3,2]
r = 5

Numo.gnuplot do
       set xrange: 0..20
       set yrange: 0..7
       set xlabel: "x"
       set ylabel: "y"

       # Lazy way
       set "object 1 circle front at 10,3 size #{r} fillcolor rgb \"black\" lw 4"

       plot x, y, with: :lines
end
gets # wait
```

numo-gnuplot covers most of the official examples of gnuplot.
So, by looking at the examples, you can easily replace the gnuplot code with Ruby one.

Comment: I know there are other libraries that may allow me to do what I need for this very project, and maybe I'll investigate them. However my question here is really about Gnuplot more than my own project. But if it is too complex, I'll make sure to give a look at numo gnuplot.